# Displaying discount on e-commerce site

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, users, experience

When displaying discount on e-commerce site (desktop and mobile), which option will perform better? And why?

#### Amazon does this:

> **Discount**
>   10% Off or More
>   25% Off or More
>   50% Off or More
>   70% Off or More

#### Is that ^ better in some way that this:

> **Discount**
>   10%-30% off
>   30%-50% off
>   50%-70% off

To clarify, I´m asking about how to display numerous sales groupings.
For example Amazon do this
[image]

Is this option better than this?

[image]

Comment: the question is not clear....are you asking what is the best sale in value or how to display numerous sales groupings?

Comment: are they check boxes? search filters? what is their behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to communicate a discount message apart from a specific product listing. So ...

### Consider all your options

There are a few more solutions (possibly more common) that you've left off your list:

> Save 10% and up
>   Save up to 70%
>   Up to 70% off

### Keep it simple

Conventional wisdom is to first evaluate how to keep the message (essentially a call to action in this case) as concise as possible.

What is the most succinct way to communicate the offer? Of your two options, 'or more' takes that prize, primarily due to the visual complexity of too many numbers and percent signs in the alternative.

Also consider your promotional graphics. Does one format work better in the approved style than the other? This shouldn't be the driver (graphics should be altered to serve the purpose), but it's worth considering.

### Remember the psychological factor

Clear and concise are nice from a usability perspective, but this is e-comm — sometimes the business comes first. Take these two options for example:

> Save 10% and up

*OR*

> Save up to 30%

Any marketer with more than an hour of experience will bet their paycheck on the second option. It *will* generate more engagement. And as long as the products on the other side of that offer are desirable, it will generate more sales.

Users are drawn in by big percentage savings. 10% is a bare minimum to even consider it an offer. It's not particularly attractive. 30% is a meaningful savings.

### Trigger words

Building on the psychological aspect of marketing, you should also consider the trigger value of the words/characters used.

There are two key triggers in the examples listed here: **`Save`** and **`%`**. But you may find other triggers work just as well or better, which brings me to my next point ...

### Never stop testing

I say this a lot. Every audience is unique in some nuanced way. We're talking here about minor adjustments to the wording. Your audience may not respond the same way as the groups I've tested.

Comment: I think your point of view is really interesting, and the "Save up to 30%" is a new concept that I can test. I think what are you saying is a really good option to test and see which option is the best. Thinking on a mobile solution do you think it can still work this way? do yo have any website I can see?

Comment: On this topic, I don't see a huge divide between mobile and desktop. The key on mobile will be creating a sense of urgency about the offer, but that same concern will contribute to conversions on desktop as well.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't have any great examples. I'd recommend surveying the industry and seeing what big and small players do. But, again, the best info you'll find is testing your own customers.

Comment: `Of your two options, 'or more' takes that prize, primarily due to the visual complexity of too many numbers and percent signs in the alternative.`

Maybe this is just me being a numbers-guy, but I would've preferred the `10% - 30% Off`-style over the `Off or more`-style, fewer words. The Steam store seems to be currently using `-10 ~ 30%`  which I find very intuitive and easy to read (no words at all).

That said, I agree with your `up to 30%` suggestions.